# R: creating variable conditionally based off two shift statements

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set like the following:

```
id   age    mod  
1    1      1
1    5      0
1    6      1  
1    7      1
1    9      1   
2    3      0
2    4      1
```

And I'd like to create the variable first and give it a value of true only for the first occurrence of each episode of mod (each episode begins when mod==1). An episode can be defined as a series (or standalone day) of mod==1 in which age is incrementing by 1 or age is incrementing by 2. In other words, if age== 2 and mod==1, age==3 and mod==0 and age==4 and mod==1, ages 2-4 are still apart of the same series because they are still within 2 days of each other.

So ideally the final data set would look like this:

```
id   age    mod  first
1    1      1    TRUE
1    5      0    FALSE
1    6      1    TRUE
1    7      1    FALSE
1    9      1    FALSE
2    3      0    FALSE
2    4      1    TRUE
```

I've tried using lag statements within data.table and have not be successful.

Comment: Can you please add more cases to the sample dataset? Did you mean age==3 and mod==1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

The simple condition is that `mod[i]==1 & mod[i-1]==0`. That is, if a row has a `mod` value of 1 and the previous row has a `mod` value of 0, then it is flagged as `first`.

This should work:

```
d = read.table(text='id   age    mod  
1    1      1
1    5      0
1    6      1  
1    7      1
1    9      1   
2    3      0
2    4      1', header=T)

d$first[1] = (d$mod[1]==1)
d$first[2:nrow(d)] = (d$mod[2:nrow(d)]==1 & d$mod[1:nrow(d)-1]==0)
```

Comment: I wish It was this simple. I had tried something similar, but the issue I was having is that some obs have age that are greater than 2 days before/after the obs. Since each episode must only have mod values that are within 2 days of each other, this wouldn't work. Do you have a method that would include age as well? Thanks! @Aziz

Comment: I see. I was only looking at `mod` and I missed the part about ages and days. Can you please provide a larger example of the data set (as requested in the comment by @chinsoon12 too)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should meet your criteria. This could probably be done in a long, convoluted one-liner, but I think breaking it into multiple steps for the sake of clarity will meet the same ends without a meaningful performance hit.

```
library(data.table)

## Note - I added a couple more sample rows here
DT <- fread("id   age    mod  
1    1      1
1    5      0
1    6      1  
1    7      1
1    9      1   
2    3      0
2    4      1
3    1      1
3    5      0
3    9      1  
3    10     1")


## Create a column to track jumps in age
DT[, agejump := age - shift(age, n = 1L, fill = NA, type = "lag") > 2L, by = .(id)]

## Create a column to define continued sequences
DT[, continued := mod == 1 & shift(mod, n = 1L, fill = NA, type = "lag") == 1L, by = .(id)]

## backfill the first row of NA's for each id for both variables with FALSE
DT[DT[, .I[1], by = .(id)]$V1, c("agejump","continued") := FALSE]

## define first
DT[,first := (mod == 1 & continued == FALSE | mod == 1 & continued == TRUE & agejump == TRUE)]

print(DT)

#     id age mod agejump continued first
#  1:  1   1   1   FALSE     FALSE  TRUE
#  2:  1   5   0    TRUE     FALSE FALSE
#  3:  1   6   1   FALSE     FALSE  TRUE
#  4:  1   7   1   FALSE      TRUE FALSE
#  5:  1   9   1   FALSE      TRUE FALSE
#  6:  2   3   0   FALSE     FALSE FALSE
#  7:  2   4   1   FALSE     FALSE  TRUE
#  8:  3   1   1   FALSE     FALSE  TRUE
#  9:  3   5   0    TRUE     FALSE FALSE
# 10:  3   9   1    TRUE     FALSE  TRUE
# 11:  3  10   1   FALSE      TRUE FALSE
```